# MySQL Error: #1046 - No database selected

Tags: mysql

I ran into an issue using MySQL 5.5 running on xampp (Version 1.8.1). I kept receiving the "#1046 - No database selected" error when trying to add a table to a database via the console window.

I had made sure the database was selected "USE database_name;", however I was still receiving the same error.

I double checked and found all privileges for the user were enabled. Frustrated, I "Uncheck All" then "Check All" global privileges.

I logged out, 
restarted server services, 
closed the browser, 
restarted server services,
opened browser,
and logged in.

Now I am able to create tables via the console. It appears to me resetting the privileges fixed the issue.

Can anyone tell me if this is a known bug, if I got lucky, or missed the point completely? Documentation I found concerning this error was mostly for importing a database and using the "Use Database_Name;" to ensure the database was indeed selected. However I don't believe this was the issue.

Please Note: While trying to create new databases I am once again receiving the #1046 error. The method I mentioned above was a fluke and is not allowing me to create any new tables inside a new database. However I am still able to work with the first database I created.

Answer (score 62):

I know this is a very late answer but for the benefit of anyone coming across this error, it might also pop up when the database name includes a dash. If so you need to put backticks around the database name, like so:

```
GRANT ALL ON `database-name`.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

The error message is not very helpful as it suggest you need to select a database in order to grant privileges to a user.

Comment: In terraform this doesn't work, but at least I know now that it's an issue with dashes, started to use underscores instead

Answer (score 15):

Another late answer but this can also happen when the table name (.*) is not specified. I ran fixed by adding the .* after database name to get it to work.

Before:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db_name TO ...
```

After:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db_name.* TO ...
```

This change fixed the somewhat ambiguous error "ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected"

Answer (score 1):

If privileges have been directly inserted into the table 'user' (many web frontends such as phpMyAdmin do that), one needs to execute `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` (phpMyAdmin has a button for this) or restart the server to reload the privileges. Neither is required when `GRANT` is used.

Comment: nice catch - that *may* have been the case here. The reason why software like phpMyAdmin does require a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` (and has a button for that) is so that you don't directly lose your rights if you make a mistake or want change the privileges of the user you are working with.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I tried your solution and it doesn't work on any new databases I've created. I tried to repeat the process I mentioned above but it seems the first time was a fluke. It's strange because I can work on the first database but no new databases.

Comment: Could indeed be just a bug. What I don't seem to understand is what console you're actually referring to. From what I can tell so far, you used phpMyAdmin's query window. What happens when you try the real thing, namely the MySQL command line client or the MySQL query browser to execute `create database ...;grant ...;use ...;create table ...;` in a sequence and more importantly, trough a single session/connection?